# Shifting up widgets with animation when a top widget go invisible in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, jetpack-compose-animation

I tried to make Toolbar(just a simple Text) invisible with AnimatedVisibility but after that i saw the below TextField comes up to the Toolbar(invisible) position but with no smooth animation.

Anyone knows how to chain them like when the Toolbar got invisible the TextField comes up with nice and smooth animation?